# c# beats music api cover

Tags: c#, beatsmusic

How do I get bigger album cover images on beats music web api?
I've written a c# method to grab the cover, but I always get a 200x200px image.
There is an option to set the size of the picture, but there's always this error thrown

```
{"code":"InvalidArgument","message":"Invalid size: 600x600"}
```

I use this link to grab the image

```
https://partner.api.beatsmusic.com/v1/api/albums/[album_id]/images/default?size=600x600&client_id=[my_client_id]
```

I've read through the documentation (https://developer.beatsmusic.com/docs/read/images/Albums_Fetch_Default#Parameters), so there must be the size parameter.

I also tried to change "/images/default" to "/images/large" or "/images/thumb".

**Solution:**

Where I've insert `600x600` you have to insert one of these: `thumb`, `small` ,`medium` or `large`!

Comment: `size` must be any of the mentioned `thumb`, `small`, `medium` or `large`. What happens when you use one of those? "It's no use" is no error message, please be exact and complete.

Comment: I now got the error and it work if I use "size=large". Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each size: thumb, medium, large, you should specify the corresponding size: thumb   180x80
small   190x230
medium  375x250
large   750x500

There is more information on this page: 
https://developer.beatsmusic.com/docs/read/images/Albums_Fetch_Default

Comment: instead of "&size=600x600" I have to use "&size=large", thank you :D